# indirect.ext (from morefunc add-on) returns NAME error in Excel

Tags: excel-2010, excel-indirect

I'm using the indirect function that can look up externally closed workbooks from the morefunc add-on.  I get a name error in evaluate formula at the indirect.ext function. Why is the morefunc add-in not working?

I'm using Excel 2010 and Windows 7 Professional x64.  Is morefunc perhaps not compatible?  Is there a possible workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I found the solution.  When installing morefunc, there are TWO add-ons that need to be added (.xll and .xlam files).  I now have it working.  I just have to figure out how to put it to a file that's on a network drive. :-) Progress!

Any pointers on getting it to work with network drives are appreciated.